# Saving the audio file after recording is completed?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, audio-recording

I am trying to save a recorded audio file in the document folder. I tried to use `CoreData` to save the recorded audio but i cannot figure it out. What is the best way to integrate it? My code is as follows:-

```
    if(_radio.isRecording) {
        [_recordbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_radio stopRecording];
    }  else {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *recordname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.%@", [_detailItem objectForKey:@"name"], _recordingCounter++, [_radio fileExtensionHint]];
        NSString *path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:recordname];
        [_recordbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_radio startRecordingWithDestination:path];

    }
}

- (void)radio:(MeroRadio *)radio didStopRecordingWithDestination:(NSString *)path {

    NSLog(@"Did stop recording with destination: %@", path);
    [_recordbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [_recordings saveobject:[url lastpathcomponent];

}
```

`_recordings` is a `NSMutableArray`. So what is the best way to save it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

NSArray *documentsFolders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[documentsFolders objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recording.aiff"];

[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL URLWithString:path] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

    /*notify of completion*/

    NSLog(@"AssetURL: %@",assetURL);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);

    if (!error) {
        //video saved

        [[self appDelegate] showAlertWithTitle:@"Audio Saved" message:@""];

    }
    else{

        [[self appDelegate] showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.domain];

    }

}];
```